# Getting Internal server error for RewriteRule -.htaccesss

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write the RewriteRule for the following scenario

When I hit the url:          *localhost/* **example**

it needs to load the **example.php** file which is in sub folder(**pages**)

Folder structure:

```
     - pages

             - example.php

     - styles

     - scripts

     - index.php
```

my .htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.php
```

but I am getting

> *500 Internal server error*

Anyone please help me with this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rules are probably looping. Add a condition to prevent this from happening:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [L]
```

Since the rewrite engine loops until the URI stops changing, the `(.*)` matches everything, including `/pages/whatever`. So the URI keeps getting `/pages/` appended to the front of the URI.

Comment: Hi  
Thank you for your answer.

Its working fine in the server.  
But when I try in the localhost its saying Not found.

Comment: on localhost, is you htaccess file in your document root?, if not then you need to change the rules to account for the different base

Comment: in **www** folder I have 2 projects **project1** & **project2** ... .htaccess file is in **project2**

Comment: I got it .... added **project2** next to %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ ... it worked .... Thank you very much.